# Eclipse compile error 'The left parenthesis is missing from the IN expression'

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have compiled my project in Eclipse. It is a Java EE project with JPA entities.

I get this error where the `@NamedQuery` annotation is not understood when it has an `IN` clause in it.

[image]

Is this maybe a wrong dependency on a Java EE library?

Comment: Not sure, but do you need a ':' there ?

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Which versions in *Project Facets* property? There are bug reports related to this, but they are relatively old. Likely your Eclipse simply needs an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are produced by Dali (an Eclipse JPA tooling plug-in). The Dali JPQL parser cannot parse concatenated strings. You can disable the Dali JPQL parser via the Preferences:

Window > Preferences > Java Persistence > JPA > Errors/Warnings > Queries & Generators > Invalid or incomplete JPQL queries

You can find out a bit more about Dali here: https://eclipse.org/webtools/dali/

Answer (score 2):

The parser doesn't understand the `:name` syntax. Instead, it expects `(:name1, :name2, ...)`.

You can try to ignore the problem; but I think the resulting query will fail when JDBC replaces the parameter because JDBC doesn't support lists when replacing parameters (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254133/jdbc-prepared-statement-how-to-set-a-list)

Comment: is this something to do with eclipse version? My colleagues don't get this error. It compiles and deploys ok otherwise.

Comment: Maybe. Search for files which begin with `org.eclipse.jst` in both Eclipse installations and compare the versions (the numbers in the file names).

Comment: Also check `org.eclipse.jpt` might also be interesting. You can also compare feature versions in the "About" dialog of Eclipse but I find that hard to do.

Comment: eclipse is a neverending configuration nightmare

Comment: My solution is to avoid p2 and the marketplace. Instead, I download a clean install archive and then put all extensions that we want to use in our team in the `dropins/` folder. That way, we know what we get.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here, and I was using eclipse neon JEE version and eclipselink 2.6. My problem was that my persistence.xml had the JPA 1.0 schema and my project facetes was configured to JPA version 1.0. After correcting both, my problem was gone. Hope this helps someone.

Side note : The original [bug with Dali was fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367593) a long time ago. So if you still face this issue, you might have something wrong with the configuration(s).